# Javascript: innerHTML not working

Tags: javascript, html

The first innerHTML code works without any issues, however the second innerHTML code is causing problems. Its value is set to undefined.

```js
names = ["Man", "Man 2", "Man 3"];
textdata = ["RISIKESI", "This service is amazing",
  "Best RISIKESI I have so used!"
];
i = 1;

function anim() {
  text = document.getElementById("theText");
  text.innerHTML = textdata[i];
  name = document.getElementById("theName");
  name.innerHTML = names[i];
  if (i == 2) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}

var int = setInterval(anim, 2000);
```

```html
<div class="cd-testimonials-wrapper cd-container">
  <ul class="cd-testimonials">
    <li>
      <p id="theText">RISIKESI</p>
      <p id="theName" class="t">Man</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to declare your global and local variables with `var`.

Comment: You're clashing with the browser's `window.name` property.  I feel like this is a dupe, but can't find it now.  Use something other than `name` or scope the variable to the function and the problem disappears.

Comment: NB : declare your local variables with `var`, use a consistent indentation, be careful when you use spaces (id = "theName", i =1;, etc.).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its because of your variable name as `name`. You haven't used the keyword `var`, so your variable is now global. It now clashes with  `window.name`. Change the name of the variable and it should work just fine.

And, whenever your want to initialize local variables, always use the `var` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't used `var`, so you are trying to set `name` as a global, but `window.name` already exists and (because it is, internally, defined with a setter) can only be set to a string. Your HTML element object gets converted to a string, at which point the `innerHTML` property on it stops having any special meaning.

Use `var` when declaring a variable to create a locally scoped one.

You would benefit from using [JS Hint](http://jshint.com) to highlight possible issues, like this one, in your JS and [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to turn certain gotches (like this one) into errors that would be highlighted in your browser's developer tools.

Comment: With a simple example proving what you say : https://jsfiddle.net/b41gy10w/ :)

Answer (score -1):

```
var names = ["Man", "Man 2", "Man 3"];
var textdata = ["RISIKESI", "This service is amazing",
"Best RISIKESI I have so used!"];
var i =1;
var text = document.getElementById("theText");
var nameEl = document.getElementById("theName");
function anim(){
   text.innerHTML = textdata[i];
   nameEl.innerHTML= names[i];
   i!=2 ? i++ : i=0
}

var int = setInterval(anim, 2000);
```

//http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQpExv